# Recommend Next Note Purchase

Tags: beginner, haskell, finance

I have just started trying to learn Haskell and tried to think of a practical, but simple problem to try and solve.  I have a strong background in C, but am just beginning to dip my toes in the world of functional programming.

The idea came from my investing in notes on Prosper: given a list of note ratings, and a desired distribution, what should the next note purchase be, in order to most align with the desired distribution.

Here's an example:

Say I currently own 5 notes of an "A" rating, and 4 notes of a "B" rating.  If my desired distribution is 50% "A" and 50% "B", then the next note purchased should be of a "B" rating. However, if my desired distribution was 90/10, the next note should be an "A" rating.

The below code seems to work (albeit with no error checking), but feels very unreadable.  What are some ways I could refactor to make the code more readable or idiomatic to Haskell?

```
module Main where

import Data.List
import Data.Ord


main::IO()
main = print $ recommendNote [ "B", "C", "D", "D", "HR" ]  [ 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0]

noteTypes :: [String]
noteTypes = [ "AA", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "HR" ]

recommendNote :: (Ord a, Fractional a) => [String] -> [a] -> String
recommendNote notes targetDist = let y = zip (subtractLists targetDist (getDistribution notes)) noteTypes
                                in snd (maximumBy (comparing fst) y)                            

subtractLists :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
subtractLists = zipWith (-)

count :: [String] -> String -> Int
count inList x =  length $ filter (x==) inList

getNoteCount :: [String] -> [Int]
getNoteCount inList = map (count inList) noteTypes 

getDistribution :: (Fractional a) => [String] -> [a]
getDistribution inList = percentize $ map fromIntegral (getNoteCount inList)

percentize :: (Fractional a) => [a] -> [a]
percentize inList = map (/ sum inList) inList
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first post. Happy Winterbash!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Order of arguments**

As a convention, arguments in functions are always ordered from most likely to change to less likely to change.

Because this allows...

**Simplification (Currying)**

Haskell is like Math.

Look at

```
2x + x = 1 + x
```

You would like the simplify the `x`, so:

```
2x = 1
```

The same applies to your code:

```
percentize inList = map (/ sum inList) inList
```

You can omit `inList` as it is just repeated on both sides:

```
count x inList =  length $ filter (x==) inList
```

Becomes:

```
count x = length . filter (x==)
```

Now the focus is not on the transformation of the argument, but on the definition of a function as the successive application of two (or more) known ones.

Another example is:

```
getDistribution inList = percentize $ map fromIntegral (getNoteCount inList)
```

That becomes:

```
getDistribution = percentize . map fromIntegral . getNoteCount
```

This is, left to right, a description of what the function does.

**Conventional names**

I see that `inList` goes `in`side the function, and I can see that it is a `List` from the type signature, such long names are not needed.

Just use the conventional `xs` for general lists:

```
percentize xs = map (/ sum xs) xs
```

**Use `where` not `let`**

It is more natural to read from general to specific than the opposite:

```
recommendNote notes targetDist = let y = zip (subtractLists targetDist (getDistribution notes)) noteTypes
                                in snd (maximumBy (comparing fst) y)
```

Becomes:

```
recommendNote notes targetDist = snd (maximumBy (comparing fst) y)
  where
    y = zip (subtractLists targetDist (getDistribution notes)) noteTypes
```

Where you also avoid overly long lines.

**Generality**

Be optimistic and general with your types:

```
count :: String -> [String] -> Int
```

Becomes:

```
count :: a -> [a] -> Int
```

Where `a` stands for anything.

**Not everything is `get`**

`get` is a specific OO technical term, prefixing it before the function names is confusing, just drop it.

**Make tiny functions local**

Things like:

```
subtractLists = zipWith (-)
```

May be local and without a type declaration, like:

```
recommendNote notes targetDist = snd (maximumBy (comparing fst) y)
  where
    y = zip (subtractLists targetDist (getDistribution notes)) noteTypes 
    subtractLists = zipWith (-)
```

Comment: Is the remark about efficiency valid? Doesn't Haskell cache the value of `sum xs` by default inside the same function?

Comment: @joranvar actually, no, it is not faster. Benchmarking gives almost equal times. Thanks for correcting

Comment: I was just wondering myself. I know that not every function evaluation result is cached, but many are. I am not yet certain how that works. Going to read up on that :)

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic response! One question regarding currying. How would that be applied to `percentize inList = map (/ sum inList) inList` ? Since the argument is used in two places it seems like it must be made explicit.

Comment: @Free_D it could be curried (see pointfree.io ) but it's more readable not to.